# Cannot format BigDecimal: Method threw 'java.lang.NumberFormatException' exception

Tags: java, bigdecimal, decimalformat

I have the following code:

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.00");
BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("0");

new BigDecimal(df.format(amount));
```

This is my output:

```
",00" // Method threw 'java.lang.NumberFormatException' exception.
```

But what I need is:

```
0.00 (or something like that)
```

I don't have any further information, sorry.

Comment: `df.format(amount)` returns string. Why are you passing it back to `BigDecimal`. Just print the return value from `df.format(amount)`

Comment: Also, change to format to `"###0.00"` otherwise it will print `.00` and not `0.00`

Comment: Actually the above code snippet in your question, it works. So if I a doing `DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####.00");
  BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal("0");
  System.out.println(new BigDecimal(df.format(amount)));`  it does print **0.00**.  So, if you can share error stackTrace it will help.

Comment: Also as @Goion have mentioned, just print `df.format(amount)` as it returns string. But if you will print `df.format(amount)` then change the format from `####.00` (as it will print **.00**) to the format `###0.00` (it will print **0.00**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Locale` probably is probably generating an invalid number for `BigDecimal`. Try using

```
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("####0.00", new DecimalFormatSymbols(Locale.US));
```

Of course you could simply use `df.format(amount)` to show the output value

Comment: I love thee with all my heart. Thanks.